# Wrap cell text without dividing any word characters into two lines

Tags: excel, vba, string, word-wrap

[image]

As you see on the above picture, I need to wrap the cell text without dividing any word characters into two lines.
Also I want to preserve the column width. 
I made the issue words in **bold** to illustrate the problem.
These are initial cells text without any wrapping: 
*Pressure Vessel*
*Infra , Platfrom Facilities*
*Follow up Clamps , Weak Points*
My actual dataset is 11k rows. grateful for all your help.

```
Sub Wraptext()
 
   Range("A2:A4").Wraptext = True
 
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. For me text wrapping is between the words as your expected result - except the column is very small. Which version of Excel are you using? Which font? Could it be that there are hidden characters instead of a normal space between the words?

Comment: Sorry, I won't download foreign files. What you can do: select cell A2, goto the immediate window of the vbe editor and put `?asc(mid(selection,9,1))` there, enter return. If you get a value other than 32 then the space between pressure and vessel is not a normal space.

Comment: I tried and got `160` @Ike

Comment: then that is the problem - that is a non-breaking space. Therefore wrap text doesn't recognize it as word boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of this answer is fully go to @Ike and @Brennan.
I just convert it to VBA code to make it easier for anyone have the same issue.

```
Sub Replace_non_breaking_space()
 
'Chr(160) is the (non_breaking_Space)
'Chr(32) is the normal Space
 
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = ActiveSheet  'adapt to your need
 
  Dim cel As Range
   For Each cel In ws.Range("A2:A4")
      cel = Application.Trim(Replace(cel, Chr(160), Chr(32)))
   Next cel
 
  ws.Range("A2:A4").WrapText = True
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data might have 'bad spaces' in it, meaning Excel isn't correctly recognizing the space characters as the preferred place to split the text up.  Try copying the space character between Pressure and Vessel, then find and replace with a normal space character.

Edit: Now that you know your spaces are 160, do a find a replace on alt+0160 with alt+0032